# How to write custom interceptor for spring cache(@cachable)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I am caching data using spring cache. Now i want to encrypt few data before writing into cache and decrypt data while reading. So is there any way i can write custom interceptor/aop for @cachable annotation

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to get a good answer, please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit you question to include what you have attempted so far and how that is failing to meet your expectations.

Comment: Which cache library are you using? Why do you want to encrypt the data?

Comment: Just create a decorator for the `Cache` interface which does that. You don't need AOP for that.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using AOP you can simply use a decorator for your `Cache` and `CacheResolver`.

```java
public class EncodingCacheResolver implements CacheResolver {

  private final CacheResolver delegate;

  public EncodingCacheResolver(CacheResolver delegate) {
    this.delegate=delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {    
    Collection<Cache> result = delegate.resolveCaches(context);
    return result.stream().map(EncodingCache::new).collect(Collectors.toLlist());
  }
}
```

The cache implementation

```java
public class EncodingCache implements Cache {

  private final Cache delegate;

  public EncodingCache(Cache delegate) {
    this.delegate=delegate;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return delegate.getName();
  }

  public Object getNativeCache() {
    return delegate.getNativeCache();
  }

  public void evict(Object key) {
    delegate.evict(key)
  }

  public void put(Object key, Object value) {
    Object encodedValue = encode(value);
    this.delegate.put(key, encodedValue);
  }

  public <T> T get(Object key, Class<T> type) {
    Object encodedValue = delegate.get(key, type);
    return decode(encodedValue);
  }
  
  // Other Cache methods omitted but the pattern is the same 

  private Object encode(Object value) {
    // encoding logic here
  }

  private Object decode(Object value) {
    // decoding logic here
  }

}
```

Then some configuration

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCache
public void CacheConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public CacheResolver cacheResolver(CacheManager cacheManager) {
    return new EncodingCacheResolver(SimpleCache.of(cacheManager));
  } 

}
```

Haven't tested the implementation, typed it from the top of my head. But this should more or less be what you need. You don't really need AOP for this.

Comment: Yeah, that's heading in the right direction IMO. You don't need to create a custom `CacheManager` for that. You could implement `CacheResolver` yourself and return a wrapped cache at that level. Not overriding the `CacheManager` means that you can still benefit from what Spring Boot auto-configures for you.

Comment: That is even better, forgot about that one.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please post the full working code here as the snippets shared are having some compile and run issues?

Comment: This is the full working code (at least in 2020). Could be that there is a different API now or some changes. I don't update all my answers dayly to adhere for new/changed APIs (that would take me too long and I still have a job to do :) ).